# how to enable the calculated value using power shell?

Tags: 2013, powershell, calculated-column-formula

We want to enable the **calculated value** option for the Date field,add some formula in that text box.
can any one help on this?

[image]

Comment: here we can find the solution. http://www.dotnetsharepoint.com/2015/08/enable-calculated-value-option-in.html